# Adonis validator package is not getting installed

Tags: node.js, npm, adonis.js

When I try to run this command `adonis install @adonisjs/validator` it shows this error

```
ERROR  Command failed: npm i --save @adonisjs/validator
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package standard is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'E:\adonisone\familybazar\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-dfd3107e\node_modules\asynckit' -> 'E:\adonisone\familybazar\node_modules\.staging\asynckit-d5ec6aa3'

npm ERR! path E:\adonisone\familybazar\node_modules\@adonisjs\generic-exceptions\node_modules\node-exceptions
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'E:\adonisone\familybazar\node_modules\@adonisjs\generic-exceptions\node_modules\node-exceptions' -> 'E:\adonisone\familybazar\node_modules\@adonisjs\generic-exceptions\node_modules\.node-exceptions.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JOKER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-06T00_37_25_769Z-debug.log
```

I also tried to clean the npm cache. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What version of NPM are you using? You can also try deleting the project's `node_modules` folder and reinstalling everything.

Comment: Hi, I was using adonuxt. It seems adonuxt has some kind of wierd problem. To get ride of adonux problem I installed all node_modules using pure adonis and then replaced this modules with adonuxt and it worked.

thanks